# Scale JavaScript renderer graph to print

Tags: jquery, css, svg, fusioncharts

I'm generating several plots with the JavaScript renderer, configured to fit in the available width. Relevant code looks like this:

```
<div id="sales-plot">Loading...</div>
```

```css
#sales-plot{
    width: 30%;
    height: 275px;
}
```

```
FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer("javascript");
var salesPlot = null;
$("#sales-plot").each(function(){
    salesPlot = new FusionCharts("/js/FusionCharts/Pie2D.swf",
                                 "fc-" + this.id, "100%", "100%", debugMode);
    salesPlot.setJSONUrl("/data/sales-plot.json";);
    salesPlot.render(this.id);
});
```

So far so good. Problem comes when the user prints the page: the plot takes twice the available width in a A4 sheet. I've tried tweaking my print CSS code but I've hit a wall—apparently, FusionCharts calculates and hard-codes the pixel dimensions of the graph:

```
<svg height="275" version="1.1" width="379" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
style="overflow: hidden; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
-webkit-user-select: none; cursor: default; position: relative;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
```

When I use CSS to reduce the width of the `<svg>` element or any of its ancestors I only get a cropped graph:

```css
@media print{
    #sales-plot{
        width: 5cm;
        height: 3cm;
    }
}
```

The graph keeps its original size thus it overflows the container. FusionChart resizes the graph when I resize the window, but obviously not when I print.

Does this have an easy fix?

---

**Edit:** I've Googled on how to make an SVG graphic scale to fit its outer container and I've written a JavaScript hack to make such modifications:

```
function handleDrawComplete(eventObject, argumentsObject){
    var $svg = $("svg", eventObject.sender.ref);
    var w = argumentsObject.width;
    var h = argumentsObject.height;

    $svg
        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + w + " " + h)
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
        .attr("width", "100%")
        .attr("height", "100%");
    $svg[0].clientWidth = 5000;
    $svg[0].width = 5000;
    $svg[0].pixelUnitToMillimeterX = 0.8;
}
```

Funny thing now is that I can copy the generated code with the browser developer tools into a static HTML page and graph prints with the correct dimensions, but dynamically generated graphs complete ignore CSS print rules. I've composed a [fiddle with the code](http://jsbin.com/izutow/2) and this is how it looks on my Windows 7 computer (screenshots are from Firefox 22 and have been resampled to 50%; all my other browsers exhibit the same behaviour):

## Screen

[image: Screen]

## Print

(generated A4 PDF)

[image: Print]

Comment: Is print executed by script or browser's native print menu? If by script, then you could resize prior to printing.

Comment: @ShamasisBhattacharya - Native printing.

Comment: Apparently, when I am printing, I am not seeing it cropped. See [this PDF](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29785573/FusionCharts%20-%20Printed%20with%20separate%20print%20CSS%20dimensions.pdf) printed via Safari on Mac. Is it a specific browser that's erring?

Comment: @ShamasisBhattacharya - Both graphs should have the same width but the dynamic one ignores width set in `@media print{...}`, even in your PDF—print size seems to depend on screen size.

Comment: Uhm... the static SVG (upon resize during print) simply **linearly** scales the chart to new dimensions. When dynamic charts are rendered, it actually re-renders the chart to the new dimension ensuring aesthetic font sizes, etc. Do you think that is causing a problem here? See the font-sizes in [this PDF](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29785573/FusionCharts%20-%20Printed%20with%20separate%20print%20CSS%20dimensions%20very%20small.pdf) ... note that the chart is not getting cropped, it is taking the 2cm x 2cm dimensions I have set for media print.

Comment: @ShamasisBhattacharya - I think that's the root problem: FusionCharts hard-codes pixel dimensions to ensure good looking graphs. And my site has a fluid layout, which makes things worse: there's no way to know how graphs will print since they depend on the browser window width. My edit shows a workaround attempt but, weirdly enough, you're getting different results than me (I've just added some screenshots).

Comment: What browser, version and OS you took the shots in?

Comment: @ShamasisBhattacharya - Windows 7 64 bits and Firefox 22 (but all my other browsers exhibit the same behaviour).